# Querying a specific child in a recursive DOM structure

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DOM structure like this:

```
<div class="thing">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="thing">
      <div class="title"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <!-- More .thing may be here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I have a class `.thing` that has a `.title` and `.content`. The contents of `.content` may be another `.thing`. The issue I'm having is that given an arbitrary `.thing`, I want to be able to query its `.content` and `.title` without querying anything inside of `.content`.

One way to do this would be to query the child directly, e.g.

```
const thing = ... // get some .thing
const title = thing.querySelector(':scope > .title')
```

The issue with this is that I want to be able to insert an arbitrary number of elements in between `.thing` and `.title`. One idea I had was to use the `:not` pseudo-class:

```
const title = thing.querySelector('.title:not(.content *)').
```

The theory behind this is that I want a title that isn't a child of content. This works for the top-level title, but doesn't work for nested things. What's the best way to query for this?

Answer (score -1):

give a data-attribute to the content you specifically want to grab.

Example:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("[data-getter='title']");
console.log(div);
```

```css
[data-getter="title"] {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-getter="title">
     <p>random text</p>
  </div>
   <div>2nd text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to assume `.title` is a direct child of `.thing`.

Comment: @Max presented another solution